# Specified file does not exist: "~/Scripts/telerik.grid.js"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

After publishing my asp.net mvc 3 application in my local IIS, I am getting the below mentioned error.

Specified file does not exist: "~/Scripts/telerik.grid.js".

This error is not coming when I and debugging it directly from visual studio.

This is only coming after it is published and browsed through IIS.

Comment: Is the file included in your project? Only included files are published, so probably you can't see the file in Visual Studio unless you turn on "Show all files" in the Solution Explorer?

Comment: The files are included in the project....It is working properly when I am browsing it directly from visual studio. But when I am publishing and deploying the same in my local IIS, I am getting this error.

Comment: Can you surf to that file after publishing? Is it on the server?

Comment: @StevenLemmens Thanks a lot. After publishing it manually, this particular error is not coming anymore. But telerik is not working properly. I am getting a different error in the browser console now. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'grid' of undefined"

Comment: Maybe some more files are missing. It's hard to say without knowing your project. I don't have any experience with Telerik either, so no idea.

Comment: I will post my answer as a real answer (instead of a comment) to this question. So you can accept that answer, so this question gets closed.

Comment: @StevenLemmens Thanks for your help!!!! Now it is working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to check:

Is the file included in your project? Only included files are published, so probably you can't see the file in Visual Studio unless you turn on "Show all files" in the Solution Explorer?
If so, try publishing the file manually.

Another good test is to try surfing to the file. If that doesn't work, the file wasn't published to the server for whatever reason. This is the most likely problem.